# Highcharts - PDF export format; font sizes for bar chart axis

Tags: pdf, highcharts, fonts, export

I have a dynamic chart that allows the user to switch between pie, bar and line charts (in the full deployment the user can switch Ajax data as well).

The export to PDf is causing me some issues. I can adjust the font size and style on the pie chart using:

```
    exporting: {
        enabled: false,
        sourceWidth: 842,
        sourceHeight: 595,
        chartOptions: {
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '7px',
                            lineHeight: '7px'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when I export a bar chart, the xAxis font size is still to large.
I tried:

```
    exporting: {
        enabled: false,
        sourceWidth: 842,
        sourceHeight: 595,
        chartOptions: {
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '7px',
                            lineHeight: '7px'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis: [{
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '7px'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

Which altered the font size beautifully, unfortunately it removed all my custom xAxis labels and replaced them with numbers.

I have a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/spencerplanton/dr0au6kg/5/
Which allows you to see the issue.

I apologise in advance for the slightly verbose nature of the example, but it has been lifted from several sources and a much larger dynamic chart application.

Any help formatting the PDF export bar chart axis font size would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: Hi @Spencer, Could you check the example? When I switch to the bar chart and export to PDF, I do not see any numbers as `xAxis` labels.

Comment: Hi, The fiddle does not include the xaxis code above, it is still showing the xaxis labels with the correct text but too large (probably about 13px). I omitted the code because otherwise you would not see the custom labels with the correct text and wrong fontsize. You would see correctly sized fonts but have no idea what the text is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options for arrays are overwritten. You need to set:

```
        exporting: {
            ...,
            chartOptions: {
                ...,
                xAxis: [{
                    type: 'category',
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '7px'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
        }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ryn5p20q/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions

Comment: Thank you for casting some much needed light on the subject. I never knew that the options were overwritten.It makes sense now I have seen it in action but I am not so sure that I would have found that without help. Many thanks.